# Acess Widget View from app ContentView in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

What I want to do it display Widget Views on my app Home Screen like they do in this app:

[image: ColorWidgets App]

I've tried just calling `WidgetEntryView` from my app, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create *separate* files just for your `View` and `Entry`:

```
struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
}
```

```
struct SimpleWidgetEntryView: View {
    var entry: SimpleProvider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        Text(entry.date, style: .time)
    }
}
```

2. Set the target membership for these files to **both** App and Widget.

- [Xcode “Targets” with multiple build configurations](https://medium.com/@andersongusmao/xcode-targets-with-multiples-build-configuration-90a575ddc687)

It is important that you select only these two files - make sure you don't accidentally add your `@main` Widget / WidgetBundle to the App target.

3. Display the Widget View directly in the ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
     var body: some View {
        SimpleWidgetEntryView(entry: .init(date: Date()))
    }
}
```

---

<sub>Here is a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/pawello2222/WidgetExamples#preview-widget) with different Widget examples including the Preview Widget.</sub>

Comment: Managed to get this working! Works like a charm, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [view controller](https://gist.github.com/EmilioPelaez/0fbc73935305c711b8d88c303f7812c4) to display widgets in a UIKit app. I built it to automate my screenshots but you can use it as a reference.

You can see how it looks [here](https://twitter.com/EmilioPelaez/status/1306011824840638464).

It has support for all widget sizes, and while it doesn't have the exact dimensions, I think it does a decent enough job.

Like it was already mentioned, you'll need to add some of your widget view files to your app target as well.